# What is the best way for an user to enter their 'city' in a web app?

Tags: api, google-maps, web-applications, geolocation

Apologies if the question is a bit vague.
This is what I want to achieve in my web application, which can have users from anywhere.

I want to be able to find the proximity of two users, from their cities. The application is not asking for an address or any exact location. I'm trying to find the proximity of users through their residing cities.

The application let the users choose their country and state via drop down lists. However, I'm not sure what is the efficient way to achieve this with cities.

I need the application to be:

- Let the users enter cities by choosing from a list. That way, there wont be misspellings, etc.
- Need to be able to determine the proximity of two users by the cities. So I need a way to somehow get the longitude and latitude of the city.

So my questions are:

- Is there a standard list of cities for each country/state? How does web applications suggest cities while we are typing?
- Is Google distance matrix the best way to implement this? https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix/intro

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of online plugins for lists of cities.
Look into: http://www.jqueryscript.net/form/City-Autocomplete-Plugin-with-jQuery-Google-Places-API.html

Also, for the distance approx., you should take a look into MongoDB.
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/calculate-distances-using-spherical-geometry-with-2d-geospatial-indexes/

Comment: Thank you. Was not aware of this feature in MongoDB.